# php for full url yoast

Tags: php, url, dns, canonical-link

I am new to php.
I am using Wordpress and yoast.

However, the yoast plugin is not writing the canonical correctly. I wish to write the canonical so that it uses the syntax

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.travelideology.com/about/">
```

However, it is writing

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https:/about/">
```

Would be happy if someone can let me know what is wrong with my code.

The code is as follows:

```
function my_wpseo_canonical( $canonical ) {

    global $post;
    $attachment = get_post( $post->ID );

    $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
    $cleansed = $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $cleansed2 = get_permalink($attachment);
    $canonical = $cleansed . $cleansed2;
    return $canonical; 
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'my_wpseo_canonical' );
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function my_wpseo_canonical( $canonical ) {

global $post;
$attachment = get_post( $post->ID );

    $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
$cleansed = $protocol . "://" .site_url(). $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$cleansed2 = get_permalink($attachment);
$canonical = $cleansed . $cleansed2;
return $canonical; 
    }
```

Comment: also try  home_url()